# Thymeleaf calls login page multiple times (spring boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
Structure

java
-example
--controller
---LoginController
--security
---SecurityConfig

resources
-templates
--landingpage
---login.html
--about.html
```

This is controller

```
    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @GetMapping("/login")
        public String login()
        {


            return "landingpage/login";
        }

   @RequestMapping("/about")
    public String about() {
        return "about";
    }

    }
```

This is security config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();
//                .and()
//                .logout()
//                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
//                .clearAuthentication(true)
//                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
//                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
//                .permitAll()
//                .and()
//                .exceptionHandling()
//                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("manager").password("password").roles("MANAGER");
    }

}
```

This is loginhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

</head>
<body class="login-page">
    <div class="login-container">
        <div class="login-branding">
            <a href="/dashboard"><img src="../../static/images/logo.png" alt="Clevex" title="Clevex"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="login-content">
            <h2><strong>Welcome</strong>, please login</h2>

            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                </div>
                <p class="text-center"><a href="/forgot-password">Forgot your password?</a></p>
            </form>
            <p><a href="/" th:href="@{/}">Back to home page</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Load JQuery-->
    <script src="../../static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I go to 
http://localhost:8080/login

and it shows me login page. It shows login form but in console, i see those errors

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/login' because
>   its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
>   checking is enabled. login:1 [DOM] Input elements should have
>   autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"): (More info:
>   https) ​

And when i make debug mode on and refresh, it calls `/login` endpoind 6 times and then brings login form .

WHen I put wrong username/password and hit submit, it calls login 5 times. For `user` and `password` (which is defined in securityconfig), it calls 6 times but cant go to `abouthtml`.

For wrong or true username - password, it redirects to
http://localhost:8080/login?error

When i go to 
http://localhost:8080

it calls login endpoint 1 time then shows blank page.

In console no error.

This is pomxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- do you like thymeleaf? -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- optional, it brings userful tags to display spring security stuff -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What I want is, simple login form. With `inMemoryAuthentication`, I defined user and password. And it should go to `about.html` after succesfull login with that credential but It cant go.

For `manager` is same too.

I tried to disable securityconfig, some `antmatchers`.

https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-form-login-example/

this is also same as me but still same.

Why does it call multiple times?

Comment: Maybe it has nothing to do with the real issue but... You dont need a request mapping at "/login", even if it is a GET mapping. Just try removing the @GetMapping on "/login" and trying again. Everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: @GabrielPimenta i tried both, request and get mapping. But nothing changed. Also most examples are like that ; for example https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-form-login-example/

Comment: I think i found. It is about id values

Comment: @CanerAydın you mean ids of login form inputs?

Comment: Yes @AlexeyUsharovski but still calls login endpoind multiple times. I think because of `       .loginPage("/login")` it goes that endpoind

Comment: Another idea is  .anyRequest().authenticated() option. Do you really need it? How I understand that's put all content under Spring Security protection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you don't specify loginProcessingUrl in Spring Security settings. Use loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser") method and after that send POST request to specified specified URL.

```
<form th:action="@{/authenticateTheUser}" method="post">
```

An example of such kind of settings

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll();
```

Comment: Maybe he could try explicitly specifying the login processing URL, but spring security uses a POST request to "/login" by default, and that's what he is doing. Either way, it is worth the try.

Comment: Another point is that input fields in login form don't have specified name attribute. Not sure it's obligatory but better to make the inputs named as username and password.

Comment: I changed login.html action to `<form th:action="@{/authenticateTheUser}" method="post">` and added `    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")` to securityconfig. But still same. Nothing more I added. I also added labels both input fields.